# In C++, why does auto not work with std::atomic?

Tags: c++

General recommendation online seems to be to use `auto` where possible.

But this doesn't work:

```
auto cnt = std::atomic<int>{0};
```

While this works fine:

```
std::atomic<int> cnt {0};
```

Is there a recommended way to use this with `auto`? Or should I just assume that `auto` is not possible with this?

Comment: If I compile with `g++` using `-std=c++17`, it works just fine. Fails on C++11/C++14 standards.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`std::atomic` is immovable because it has a [deleted copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/atomic). Prior to C++17, `auto cnt = std::atomic<int>{0};` tries to call the move constructor to move the temporary into `cnt`, so you can't use `std::atomic` with almost always auto.

C++17 brought us [mandatory copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision#Mandatory_elision_of_copy.2Fmove_operations), so `auto cnt = std::atomic<int>{0};` works fine, not calling any move constructor but instead initializing the object in-place.

Comment: You're right! Switching from `C++14` to `C++17` made the error go away.